# How to reset Dock to default / vanilla settings?

Tags: dock, expose

After migrating from macOS 11.x on a Mac Pro to a new MacBook Pro with macOS 12.x, I've found that Exposé hangs like crazy and there are strange things with the display wallpaper backgrounds among many other oddities. How does one use a "nuclear" option to obliterate all Dock/Exposé and such controlled services attached thereunto on macOS?

Comment: You're looking for something like `killall dock`?

Comment: Nope, wanting to reset all of its preferences to "factory defaults," etc. as well so that there are no lingering settings remaining. It would be nice to [k|d]trace the system calls out so as to discover all files that the process wants to read and then be able to delete or empty these - or at the very least scrutinize them and/or restore them from a vanilla fresh install system.

Comment: How about just deleting `com.apple.dock.plist` then?

Comment: That did not seem to be sufficient back when I was digging around in this. I've moved past it now, but it would still be nice to have reference to. Apple is just increasingly making life difficult for advanced users and cheaper/less rich for new users.

Comment: I also suppose you have tried running `defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock` in Terminal?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Back in the day it just didn't do the trick. I really need to break down and do system traces at some point on everything and document it thoroughly. It would be nice to have a website that would go through each (including old) OS release to document all default settings and files to see the evolution and be able to have better troubleshooting options. Then, extrapolate that into an AI corpus for specific macOS bug/trouble resolution training.